# Can you know whether free() was successful in C without crashing?

Tags: c, free

`malloc()` returns a null pointer if the allocation was unsuccessful. `free()` unfortunately does not return whether deallocation was successful, as its signature is:

```
void free(void* ptr)
```

Is it possible to:

1. Attempt `free()` and know whether the freeing was successful or not without the debugger crashing the app for you?
2. Get beforehand whether calling `free()` on a pointer will result in a failure or success?

Comment: As long as you pass a valid pointer (or `NULL`) and you don't have any other undefined behavior that could have corrupted the allocator, you can assume that [`free`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free) will always "succeed".

Comment: Setting ptr to NULL has no relevance to success or failure.

Comment: @user3121023 Allocating zero bytes may or *may not* return a `NULL` pointer.  It depends on the implementation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As far as the C standard cares:

If the pointer you got returned to from `malloc()` is equal to the pointer you pass to `free()`, then `free()` will always be successful. The only error check available is to compare the pointer with a copy of the original address, before passing it to `free()`. Example:

```
type_t* foo = malloc(sizeof(*foo));
type_t* const original = foo;
...

if(foo == original)
{
  free(foo);
}
else
{
  halt_and_catch_fire();
}
```

If you need more advanced error handling than that, you'll have to use OS-specific API functions.

Comment: Detail: "pointer ... from malloc() is equal to the pointer you pass to free(), then free() will always be successful." has the exception that calling `free()` twice on the same allocated pointer is UB.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to:
> ...
>
> 2. Get beforehand whether calling `free()` on a pointer will result in a failure or success?

Yes! If your program is correct, `free()` can only succeed. If `free()` could possibly fail, your program is incorrect by definition.

I know that isn't really what you meant, but making your program *statically* correct is the right way forward.

---

To find bugs in your memory handling, you can use an error-checking `malloc/free` (such as glibc gives you when running with `MALLOC_CHECK_=1` - set other platforms may have their own mechanisms), or to use something like `valgrind` or an address sanitizer

Note that these *are* logic bugs which you should then fix ... then your program will be statically correct again.

Answer (score 2):

The MSVC version of this C-API function sets `errno`.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/we1whae7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx.

Comment: It may be able to set errno sometimes, but still, as the page says, " Attempting to free an invalid pointer ... may affect subsequent allocation requests and cause errors", meaning even for MSVC it is still UB to free a pointer not allocated by a proper call.